# i want to use a drop down list to choose the different table in php ,how to do this?

Tags: php, html

```
databases:school

table :student
table :teacher

select name="booktype"

$selectOption = $_GET['booktype'];
```

can I use? ==> `select * from **$selectOption** where class = 3A`

Comment: it would be better to use `switch`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table name as parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can:

```
$selectOption = pg_escape_string($_GET['booktype']);

use "select * from {$selectOption} where class = 3A"
or  "select * from ".$selectOption." where class = 3A"
```

Comment: if it helps, you can check the `check` button left-side of my answer

Comment: tables and columns cant be used as parameters - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter

Comment: NOTE: You cannot use a prepared parameter for the table name! You have to sanitize the table name yourself before using it in the SQL query.